# How would you build a windowless application with C++/Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5

How would you build a windowless application with C++/Qt5? Do I have to use QDialog or QWidget?

For example, [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) has no window border and the background around the text box is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you're looking for :

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html

This is a tutorial on how to make a shaped and borderless window with Qt.

It's for Qt4.8 though, i think it should work on Qt5.

EDIT : Found the Qt5.0 version : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/widgets-shapedclock.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a QWidget with `Qt::SplashScreen` or `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`. Check all the other [window flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/widgets-windowflags.html).